# Twitter API Limits when using statuses/lookup endpoint

Tags: twitter

simple question, (I was not able to find answer on twitter api doc)

following get request

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json?include_entities=true&id=657208379442597888%2C657215510283730944

is request to get 2 tweets by theirs ids.

Simple question : in the point of the Twitter API Limits, when exectuting this request it will be considered as 1 or 2 calls ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be counted as a **single request**. Since you can ask for up to 100 tweets, but the rate limit for app auth is 60, that only makes sense.

However, you can prove that by just checking the rate limit response headers. If you make the same request twice (and no other app is making requests on the user's behalf, or if you're the only one using the app's auth), you should see the `X-Rate-Limit-Remaining` header only decrease by one.